# First C++ Program : Simple Calculator

Tags: c++

Usage :

### Multiplication

---

Multipliction is simple, Enter your first digit in (eg. 1)
Enter your operator (x)
Enter your second digit in (eg. 1)

### Squaring

---

Enter your first digit in (eg. 1)
Enter your operator (s)

### Cubing

---

Enter your first digit in (eg. 1)
Enter your operator (c)

### Division

---

Division is also simple, Enter your first digit in (eg. 1)
Enter your operator (/)
Enter your second digit in (eg. 1)

### Subtraction

---

Enter your first digit in (eg. 1)
Enter your operator (-)
Enter your second digit in (eg. 1)

## Code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// Function Declaration
int multiply(int firstnumber, int secondnumber, char operation);
int square(int firstnumber, char operation);
int cube(int firstnumber, char operation);
int divide(int firstnumber, int secondnumber, char operation);
int subtract(int firstnumber, int secondnumber, char operation);

int main(){
    // Variable Declaration :
    int number1;
    int number2;
    char operation;

    // User Input :
    cout << "Enter the first number" << endl;
    cin >> number1;

    cout << "Enter the operator" << endl;
    cin >> operation;

    cout << "Enter the second number (leave blank for cube and square)" << endl;
    cin >> number2;

    cout << "This is your sum." << endl;
    cout << number1 << operation << number2 << endl;


    // Calculating :

    int result;

    char m = 'x';
    char sq = 's';
    char c = 'c';
    char d = '/';
    char s = '-';

    if (operation == m) {
        result = multiply(number1, number2, operation);
    } else if (operation == sq) {
        result = square(number1, operation);
    } else if (operation == c) {
        result = cube(number1, operation);
    } else if (operation == d) {
        result = divide(number1, number2, operation);
    } else if (operation == s) {
        result = subtract(number1, number2, operation);
    } else {
        cout << "Wrong operator input. Try again" << endl;
        return 2;
    }

    // Outputing Result :
    cout << "The result is : " << result << endl;
    return 0;
}

// Function Definition
int multiply(int firstnumber, int secondnumber, char operation) {
    return firstnumber * secondnumber;
}
int square(int firstnumber, char operation) {
    return firstnumber * firstnumber;
}
int cube(int firstnumber, char operation) {
    return firstnumber * firstnumber * firstnumber;
}
int divide(int firstnumber, int secondnumber, char operation) {
    return firstnumber / secondnumber;
}
int subtract(int firstnumber, int secondnumber, char operation) {
    return firstnumber - secondnumber;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Avoid using `using namespace std;`

Find more details here [why `using namespace std;` is considered bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

### Use `'\n'` for adding newline

`std::endl` doesn't just add newline but it also flushes the stream. More details about it [`std::endl` vs `'\n'`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213907/stdendl-vs-n)

### Refactor into functions

Make a function for calculation. What if you'd want to calculate twice? By making it into a function you can simply call it as needed.

Example:

```
int calculate(...){ ... }

int main(){
  int result1 = calculate(2, 3, 'x');
  int result2 = calculate(2, 'c');
}
```

### Leverage STL

STL [`functional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/functional) header has

- [`std::divides`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/divides) for division.
- [`std::minus`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/minus) for subtraction.
- [`std::multiplies`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/multiplies) for multiplication.
- Example usage:

  ```
  std::minus<int>{}(10, 9)  // -> 10 - 9 is performed
  std::divides<int>{}(3, 2) // -> 3 / 2 is performed
  ```

### Remove unnecessary parameters from the function.

`char operation` parameter is never used. It doesn't serve any purpose and can be removed.

### switch-case

You could use `switch` for mapping char to operation. And to avoid writing `operation == /*op*/` for each operation in every if and elif.

```
switch(op){
    case 'x': 
        return std::multiplies<int>{}(num1, num2);
    case '/':
        return std::divides<int>{}(num1, num2);
    case '-':
        return std::minus<int>{}(num1, num2);
    case 'c':
        return cube(num1);
    case 's':
        return sqaure(num1);
    default:
        /* Handle when `op` is other than [-, /, x, c, s] */
};,
```